# Argument to ivy-read action when collection is an alist

Tags: ivy, association-lists

The documentation of `ivy-read` states that if the collection supplied is an alist, the selected candidate is passed as a cons cell to the function supplied in the `:action` argument.

So why does the code snippet below return `"C1"` or `"C2"`, depending on the selection, and not `(1 2 3)` or `(3 4 5)`, respectively?

```el
(ivy-read "Choose: "
          (list (cons "C1" (list 1 2 3)) (cons "C2" (list 3 4 5)))
          :action (lambda (x) (cdr x)))
```

I can work around this by doing something like the following, but I don't understand why I have to.

```el
(let (tmp)
  (ivy-read "Choose: "
            (list (cons "C1" (list 1 2 3)) (cons "C2" (list 3 4 5)))
            :action (lambda (x) (setq tmp (cdr x))))
  tmp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does the code snippet below return `"C1"` or `"C2"`, depending on the selection, and not `(1 2 3)` or `(3 4 5)`, respectively?

Because the argument passed to `:action` is not, and is not documented as being, the same thing as the return value of `ivy-read`.  The value returned by `ivy-read` is usually, but not always, the same as what `completing-read` would return.  This is done to allow `ivy-completing-read` to be used as a `completing-read-function`.  Ivy `:action`s, OTOH, are intended for Ivy-specific features like non-exiting completion, multi-actions, etc.